# Autohotkey program where ~ key can toggle LMouse, Shift, and W to be held at the same time

Tags: autohotkey

I'm pretty new to autohotkey and cant figure out how to make it so that pressing the ~ key causes my left mouse button, shift, and W to be held at the same time until the ~ key is pressed again.

Comment: This guide has your answer. https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=11952

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
+`:: 
Toggle := !Toggle 
If Toggle
  {
     Send {LButton Down} {w Down} {Shift Down}
  }
 else 
   Send {LButton Up} {w Up} {Shift Up} 
 return
```